# GWT object parameter from javascript to java (JavaScriptObject to JSONObject)

Tags: javascript, gwt, callback, jsni

I have Object that I wish to pass from JavaScript to Java in GWT app.

This object may have arbitary fields. So it is different from very similar question were only number is passed. 
[Passing javascript parameter from external javascript to java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686696/passing-javascript-parameter-from-external-javascript-to-java)

I define callback like

```
public static void cbSysInfoSucces(JavaScriptObject o1) {
}
```

But I do not know how to convert `JavaScriptObject` to `JSONObject`

Could you also advice on `$entry()` function format if I wish to pass Object to java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use constructor [**JSONObject(JavaScriptObject jsValue)**](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject%29) to create a new `JSONObject` from the supplied `JavaScript` value.

Comment: Your solution sounds much more professional and correct!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem week ago and I have not found answer to that question. I simply encoded object as string and passed it to Java